# Index was outside the bounds of the array. works in 1st example but doesn't in second

Tags: c#, runtime-error

I have this example: `

```
var dic = File.ReadAllLines("settings.txt")
              .Select(l => l.Split(new[] { '=' }))
              .ToDictionary(s => s[0].Trim().ToString(), s => s[1].Trim().ToString());
                Variables.platefromtxt = dic["Plate"];
```

in my txt file I have: `"Plate = -02-"` So, when I want to output whats in there, I do this: `Variables.platefromtxt = dic["Plate"];`
Which is working fine!

I have tried to do another one:

```
var dicChatlog = File.ReadAllLines("chatlog.txt")
            .Select(l => l.Split(new[] { '|' }))
            .ToDictionary(s => s[0].Trim().ToString(), s => s[1].Trim().ToString());
```

This is what's inside my chatlog.txt: `"^3-02 ^7Adorable [COP]^8 | ^7Whale Waileer"`

So when I want to get `"^7Whale Waileer"` I should do: `Variables.name = dicChatlog["^3-02 ^7Adorable [COP]^8"]`

When I'm trying to run the application, I get "Index was outside the bounds of the array." The first example works just fine, the second one however has that error. Could any one tell me what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you certain every line of `chatlog.txt` has a `|` in it?  This error could happen if the `Split` did not find `|` and as such `s[1]` would be outside the bounds of the `Split` result.

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying, Yes, chatlog.txt had a "|" between Adorable & Whale Waileer, It's the only line in there.

Comment: There must be something else going on because your code works just fine given the input you specified. https://dotnetfiddle.net/YmDcdO

Comment: If the "only line" ends with a line end, then there are actually *two* lines, the second one being empty. You should really debug your code rather than asking here. We ain't have a crystal ball.

Comment: In each line of chatlog.txt has to be a "|". Otherwise `s[1]` is not defined.

Comment: Oh what a fail. Sorry guys, All working as expected. Thanks to rboe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var dicChatlog = File.ReadAllLines("chatlog.txt")
             .Where(l => l.Contains("|"))
             .Select(l => l.Split(new[] { '|' }))
             .ToDictionary(s => s[0].Trim().ToString(), s => s[1].Trim().ToString());
```

Comment: You're awesome. Much respect.